# I was trying to create custom answers with Node.js

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I am trying to create a custom question and answer.

I was trying to create:

*Who is your OWNER?*
And then my bot answers: *OpenAI*

I searched on Internet, but I found it for Python and others, but I didn’t find it for Node.js. Please can someone help me without closing question because any other posts didn’t help me.

Here is my *server.js* file I was trying to edit.
My bot is: text-davinci-003

```
import express from 'express'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import cors from 'cors'
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai'

setTimeout(funkcijabatonga, 3000);

dotenv.config()

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Hello from T1mur!'
  })
})

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const prompt = req.body.prompt;
    let response;

    if(prompt === "Who is your owner?"){
      response = {
        data:{
          choices:[
            {
              text: "OpenAI"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    } else {
      response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: `${prompt}`,
        temperature: 0,
        max_tokens: 3000,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0.5,
        presence_penalty: 0,
      });
    }

    res.status(200).send({
      bot: response.data.choices[0].text
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).send(error || 'Something went wrong');
  }
})


app.listen(5000, () => console.log('AI server started on http://localhost:5000'))

function funkcijabatonga()  {

  document.getElementById("stajleri").disabled=true;
  document.getElementById("stajlovi").disabled=false;
  document.getElementById("sveobicnobbrt").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("bratalica").style.display = "none";
}
```

I tried and searched, but I can’t find it for Node.js. I only find for Python, but I don’t use Python.

Comment: [A starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopenai-api%5D+javascript)

Comment: What were the exact terms you used to search the internet?

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene like i used CHATGPT in case he can help but cant, and i searched through stackoverflow and completly internet but noone created customs answers for model,, can you help or
?